# left join with 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

I want to join two tables with two columns, 
It's working in phpmyadmin. But it's not working with laravel. 
So how to convert it in laravel structure.

```
SELECT 
    `j`.*,
    `ts`.*,
    `ps`.*,
    `pn`.*,
    `c`.*,
    `planner`.*,
    `ps`.`name` AS `section_name`,
    `ps`.`id` AS `section_id`,
    `planner`.`date` AS `planner_date`,
    `pn`.`id` AS `planner_note_id`
FROM
    `planner`
        INNER JOIN
    `timeslots` AS `ts` ON `ts`.`id` = `planner`.`timeslot_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `planner_sections` AS `ps` ON `ps`.`id` = `planner`.`planner_section_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `planner_notes` AS `pn` ON `pn`.`date` = `planner`.`date` and `pn`.`contract_id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `contracts` AS `c` ON `c`.`id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `jobs` AS `j` ON `j`.`contract_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE
    `c`.`id` = 57        
        AND MONTH(`planner`.`date`) = 6
        AND `planner`.`date` >= '2017-06-13'
        AND `planner`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `planner`.`date` ASC
```

But when i put it in laravel query structure it's not working.

```
$planner_list = Planner::join("timeslots as ts","ts.id","planner.timeslot_id")
                ->join("planner_sections as ps","ps.id","planner.planner_section_id")
                ->leftJoin("planner_notes as pn","pn.date","planner.date")
                ->leftJoin("planner_notes as pn","pn.contract_id","planner.contract_id")
                ->join("contracts as c","c.id","planner.contract_id")
                ->join("jobs as j","j.contract_id","c.id")
                ->where('c.id','=',$contract_id)
                ->where('planner.date','>=',$current_date)
                ->whereMonth('planner.date',$current_month)
                ->select(['j.*','ts.*','ps.*','pn.*','c.*','planner.*','ps.name as section_name','ps.id as section_id','planner.date as planner_date','pn.id as planner_note_id'])
                ->orderBy('planner.date','ASC')
                ->orderBy('planner.timeslot_id','ASC')
                ->orderBy('section_id','ASC')
                ->get();
```

Above conversation isn't working for me.

It's also not working with ,

```
->leftJoin("planner_notes as pn","pn.date","planner.date","pn.contract_id","planner.contract_id")
```

**Edit :-** No I'm not getting any errors for it. it just considering last On condition.

```
ON `pn`.`contract_id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
```

I have one more confusion that if I write two leftjoin then On condition can overwrite or not ?

**EDIT-2 :-** 
It only returns last on condition.
Query from query log is :-

```
SELECT 
    `j`.*,
    `ts`.*,
    `ps`.*,
    `pn`.*,
    `c`.*,
    `planner`.*,
    `ps`.`name` AS `section_name`,
    `ps`.`id` AS `section_id`,
    `planner`.`date` AS `planner_date`,
    `pn`.`id` AS `planner_note_id`
FROM
    `planner`
        INNER JOIN
    `timeslots` AS `ts` ON `ts`.`id` = `planner`.`timeslot_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `planner_sections` AS `ps` ON `ps`.`id` = `planner`.`planner_section_id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `planner_notes` AS `pn` ON `pn`.`contract_id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `contracts` AS `c` ON `c`.`id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
        INNER JOIN
    `jobs` AS `j` ON `j`.`contract_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE
    `c`.`id` = 57        
        AND MONTH(`planner`.`date`) = 6
        AND `planner`.`date` >= '2017-06-13'
        AND `planner`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY `planner`.`date` ASC
```

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, please update your question to include them - "Not working" isn't a very descriptive issue statement.

Comment: @Epodax. No it just considering first On condition `ON pn.date = planner.date` not second.

Comment: I don't see any error in your query might be any data issue

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
->leftJoin('planner_notes as pn', function($join){
            $join->on('pn.date', '=', 'planner.date');
            $join->on('pn.contract_id','=','planner.contract_id');    
        })
```

or

change alias of table as

```
->leftJoin("planner_notes as pn","pn.date",'=',"planner.date")
->leftJoin("planner_notes as pnotes","pnotes.contract_id",'=',"planner.contract_id")
```

Comment: I tried with removing the brackets but problem is that everything is working fine but if I enable query log and if i print that query than it only show me one on condition it doesn't show me second condition.

Comment: print query log so that i can help

Comment: ohk sure. I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel join with multiple condition**

```
LEFT JOIN
    `planner_notes` AS `pn` ON `pn`.`date` = `planner`.`date` and `pn`.`contract_id` = `planner`.`contract_id`
```

it's equivalent to:

```
->leftJoin('planner_notes as pn', function($join){
            $join->on('pn.date', '=', 'planner.date');
            $join->on('pn.contract_id','=','planner.contract_id'); 
        })
```

laravel.com Ref: [method_on](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on)

Add an "on" clause to the join.

On clauses can be chained, e.g.

$join->on('contacts.userid', '=', 'users.id') ->on('contacts.infoid', '=', 'info.id')

will produce the following SQL:

on contacts.user_id = users.id and contacts.info_id = info.id

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's not working it only return last `on 'pn.contract_id','=','planner.contract_id'`.

Comment: No we can't put where like this because we wants result like this `planner_notes` AS `pn` ON `pn`.`date` = `planner`.`date` and `pn`.`contract_id` = `planner`.`contract_id`.

Comment: previous query is working fine for i have been using like that.

Comment: Your last option was working for me in 5.2 but may be for 5.3 it's not working. I'm not sure for that.

Comment: yeah your previous query is the solution for 5.2 but may be it's not working in 5.3

Comment: check offical document: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/JoinClause.html#method_on